# Netbeans running multimodule Maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-7

I've recently tried to work with NetBeans and I don't understand how it handles Maven multi-module projects.

My project has fairly complicated modules structure and when we're working on it (we mainly use IntelliJ community edition) we don't want to open all its modules (~50 modules) because it will take hours to load the project, instead we've created a 'workspace' module: a folder with `pom.xml` that has a packaging type pom and defines modules that I would like to load.

Lets say it defines modules A, B, C.

We have our `main` method (we don't use any type of container) in module A which is a low-level infrastructure module.

As a runtime dependency we need A, B, C. But A doesn't really depend on B, C, but rather B and C depend on A (in terms of Maven dependencies).

So we've created another module, lets call it runner, where we define all the dependencies. Our workspace `pom.xml` has module declaration of runner, so in order to run the project from IntelliJ, we use a 'classpath of module runner' while running method main in module A.

Now, How can I achieve the same affect with the latest Netbeans (7.1.2)?

I understand that question is kind of newbie's style, but I struggle with it a lot of time with no luck.

Comment: If maven Can run the Pom.xml, you should be able to open the pom.xml from within Netbeans.  Tried?

Comment: Yes, sure, it opens it. I can build my modules, but I can run my main class from netbeans so that I will take a classpath of other module. Instead when I right-click on main method and run it spawns java exec plugin and I have no idea where to compile it. I just don't want to config java exec plugin for this in my pom. All in all, it looks like NetBeans uses maven directly and doesn't create IDE specific layer as intelliJ does.

Comment: So, does it work or not?

Comment: No, doesn't work. I've made a mistake in the previous comment, I meant : "...but I can't run my main class..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just struggled with the same issue - from what's listed in the Netbeans wiki it seems that every module represents it's own Netbeans project and everything else would be expressed with project dependencies. See http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices

> A project with modules is known as a multimodule, or aggregator project. Modules are projects that this POM lists, and are executed as a group. The Maven projects in NetBeans lists these modules as "Required Projects". So you will only get the required projects list populated for Maven projects with "pom" packaging that have modules defined.